# Show tax and shipping even if these values are 0

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to show tax and shipping rows in cart and checkout pages, even if these values are 0.

Is there an easy and proper way to fulfil this requirement.

[image: Show tax and shipping even if their value is 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Set this From Here : goto Admin Panel :

`system->configuration->sales->tax->shopping cart display setting`

you can set

Include Tax In Grand Total

Display Full Tax Summary

Display Zero Tax Subtotal

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar Arora :you are welcome